# Wrong firstdayofweek set in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, datetime

Hey on a server I am working on I am getting the wrong week day for the current day i.e today

Response.Write(WeekdayName(Weekday(System.DateTime.Now)))

I am getting Thursday, where does this default get set or where can I change it. And it thinks day of the week is 4.

Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that the system time/date is correct?

Answer (score 0):

[The resolution of this property depends on the system timer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) If you adjust the server's system time, it should adjust the programs.

Comment: Where abouts can I check this i.e the current date and time is correct on server

Comment: If DateTime.Now doesn't give you what you want, adjust the clock on the server.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the default start of the week. You might try something like:

```
Response.Write(WeekdayName(Weekday(System.DateTime.Now, _
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday)))
```